# using ggplot's "annotation_raster" and reached R's "memory ceiling"

Tags: r, memory-management, annotations, ggplot2, raster

I am using R to create a floorplan of a house with several layers like below, starting from the bottom layer:

- `basemap`: a scanned version of the floorplan which I put it at the bottom layer to aid the reading
- `bed`: the house have several dozens of beds, scattered in different rooms of the house, they have different colours based on the characteristics of the residents
- `piechart`: each bed has a piechart of top of it, again the piecharts are created based on the residents' other set of characteristics, some beds have piecharts, some don't.

The `bed` and `piechart` were created based on the shp file created based on the basemap (i.e. I use Mapwindow the create a vector layer, import the basemap as raster layer and put it at the bottom, then draw the beds one by one. The bed shp file is then imported into R, the bed polygons' centroid are calculated and that centroid helps to position the piecharts)

I used `read.jpeg` to import the `basemap` to `imagematrix` object, then use the new `annotation_raster` function in `ggplot2 0.9` to put the `basemap` at the bottom map layer, since the `bed` layer is created based on the `basemap` also, the `bed` layer superimpose on the `basemap` layer perfectly in `ggplot2`.

I can create the map without problem - if the `basemap` is small enough (`3000 x 3000` pixels), now I have a `basemap` of `8000+ x 3000+` pixels (`object.size` 241823624 bytes), I did not aware of the R memory issue when I was creating the shp file, the `ggplot` object can be compiled if I have the `annotation_raster` disabled, but R keeps saying that I can allocate memory with xxxMB when I try to include the `basemap` into the `ggplot` object.

I think this is nothing to do with the compression of the jpg files, as the dimension is not changed even I further compress the jpg file. But I can't resize the jpg file as my `bed` layer is created based on the original jpg file's dimension.

Can anyone help to shrink the size of the `basemap`'s imagematrix, without changing the jpeg's dimension, or some other tricks to deal the R's memory limitation? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how to help, but I want to know what this project is about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I first created a new `basemap` image file with width and height halved, then in the `annotation_raster` I did the following:

```
chart <- chart + annotation_raster(db$temp.basemap,
                                   xmin=0,
                                   xmax=basemap.xlength*2,  # I stretched the image in R
                                   ymin=0,
                                   ymax=basemap.ylength*2)  # I stretched the image in R
```

Now the map can be compiled within R's memory limit, the drawback I can think of is the reduce in image quality, but that is bearable, as it was `8000 x 3000` originally.